# spring boot control response end in streaming

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a service whose goal is to return a sequence of events as soon as they are computed.
I want to stream the response so that a client can process a event as soon as it was computed.

This work with something along these lines:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(new StreamingResponseBody()
{
  @Override
  public void writeTo(OutputStream out)
  {
    Subscriber subscriber = new EventSubscriber(duration);
    updateService.getEventStream(subscriber);

    while (!subscriber.isComplete()) {
      try { 
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    } 
  }

}, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What happen is that I subscribe to some Event stream, and whenever an event is computed, the event is written to the outputstream:

```
public class EventSubscriber implements Subscriber<Map<String, String>>
{
...
   @Override
  public void onNext(String event)
  {
    try {
      out.write((event+ "\n").getBytes());
      out.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
...
}
```

My problem with this solution is the 'Thread.sleep(100)' which I would like to remove.

But when I remove it, when the response entity is sent to the client, the outputstream is closed.

How could I kept it open without holding on the thread ?

For example, I woul like that the outputstream is kept open until the oncomplete method of the EventSubscriber is called.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: DeferedResult do not help me here as with DeferedResult, the response is sent to the client only once everything is computed. In some sense, I would like an hybrid response between DeferedResult and ResponseEntity of StreamingResponseBody.